# Generalizing famous kinematic equation to 3D space

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics, kinematics

Everybody knows this one-dimensional kinematic equation from high school physics:
$$2a\,\Delta x = v^2 - v_0^2 \quad (\label(1)$$
which is essentially (adopting the usual abuses of notation found in undergraduate mechanics textbooks)
$$\int_{x_0}^x a \, dx = \int_{v_0}^v v \, dv $$
in the case when the acceleration $a$ is constant. Now this is justified rigorously as follows (proof is my own, all corrections/suggestions welcome):

> 1. Suppose we have the injective, twice-continously differentiable function $x : \Omega \to \mathbb R$, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R$ open, indicating the position of our particle, and the two functions
>      $$V : x(\Omega) \to \mathbb R, \qquad A : x(\Omega) \to \mathbb R $$
>      that satisfy
>      $$\dot x(\tau) = V(x(\tau)), \qquad \ddot x(\tau) = A(x(\tau)) \qquad \forall \tau \in \Omega$$
> 2. Then – for the single-variable chain rule – we must have, for some $t_0 \in \Omega$, that 
>      $$A(x(t_0)) = \frac{dV}{dy}(x(t_0))\dot x(t_0) = \frac{dV}{dy}(x(t_0))V(x(t_0)) $$
> 3. We now choose $t \in \Omega$ such that $t > t_0$, integrate both sides and use the [theorem of integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) over the interval $x([t_0,t]) = [x(t_0),x(t)]$:
>      $$\int_{x(t_0)}^{x(t)} A(\xi) \, d\xi = \int_{x(t_0)}^{x(t)} V(\xi) \frac{dV}{dy}(\xi) \, d\xi = \int_{V(x(t_0))}^{V(x(t))} \lambda \, d\lambda = \left[\frac 1 2\lambda^2\right]_{V(x(t_0))}^{V(x(t))}$$

My question would be: is there an equivalent $(1)$ in **space**? That would mean we'd be integrating vector-valued functions over some (curvelike) region in $\mathbb R^3$. I think one would have to use the multivariable version of integral substitution (also mentioned in the link above), but I'm not sure of all the details of such a derivation. I'm also guessing, since multiplication of two vectors is not well defined in Euclidean space, that we'd have dot products or square moduli in lieu of the squares on the right-hand side of $(1)$.

Comment: The original equation is essentially a statement of energy conservation, with the mass divided out: the work done by a constant force equals the change in kinetic energy. The same holds in higher dimensions, with exactly the changes you mentioned ($2a\cdot\Delta x=\|v_1\|^2-\|v_0\|^2$).

Comment: note that $V$ is not a function of $x$, but instead directly a function of $\tau$. For example, if you throw a particle straight up, the acceleration is constant, but velocity on the way up is positive, and on the way down is negative, even when you go through the same point

Comment: I get what you are saying, but my question concerns the precise situation in which one can assign to each point on the trajectory $x(\Omega)$ the velocity of the particle at that point. Actually, you made me notice that I didn't specify $x$ should be injective – edited